# How do I calculate the confusion matrix in PyTorch efficiently?

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor that contains my predictions and a tensor that contains the actual labels for my binary classification problem. How can I calculate the confusion matrix efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

After my first version using a for-loop has proven inefficient, this is the fastest solution I came up with so far, for two equal-dimensional tensors `prediction` and `truth`:

```python
def confusion(prediction, truth):
    confusion_vector = prediction / truth

    true_positives = torch.sum(confusion_vector == 1).item()
    false_positives = torch.sum(confusion_vector == float('inf')).item()
    true_negatives = torch.sum(torch.isnan(confusion_vector)).item()
    false_negatives = torch.sum(confusion_vector == 0).item()

    return true_positives, false_positives, true_negatives, false_negatives
```

Commented version and test-case at https://gist.github.com/the-bass/cae9f3976866776dea17a5049013258d